# Why text in @Html.Label in bootstrap does not align left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Im trying to align text in labels in left , but it aligns in right by default.

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        @Html.Label("7) Înregistrarea în format video a cursurilor universitare", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 align-left" })


                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To align text to the left, you need to use the class `text-left`, but you are using `align-left`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro align-left is a classname

Comment: @Justcode I understand that `align-left` is a class name. The post has the tag `twitter-bootstrap`, in bootstrap the class name to align left is `text-left` (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment). OP doesn't have it in the list of class names: `control-label col-md-5 align-left`, unless OP defined `align-left` in the CSS (not specified in the question), `align-left` is a class name that means nothing.

Comment: control-label col-md-5 text-left, doesnt work either, if i type just text-left works , but with col-md-5 doesnt want

Comment: what is the generated HTML? And the CSS? If the generated code is this: http://jsfiddle.net/96f5hv1e/, it seems to be working fine. There must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
 .form-group{
    text-aligh: left;
    float: left;

    }
```

Comment: added in bootsatrap.css doesnt want